# Validate function is not working in backbone

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I'm trying to log an error when an attribute of a variable is changed, but the validate is never being triggered, this is my code:

```
Person = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            console.log("hello world");
            this.bind('change:name', function() {
                console.log(this.get('name') + ' is now the value for the name');
            });
            this.bind('error', function(model, error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        },
        defaults: {
            name: 'Bob Hope', 
            height: 'unknown'
        },
        validate: function(attributes) {
            if(attributes.name == 'blank'){
                return 'no';
            }
        }
    });


var person = new Person();
person.set({name: 'blank'});
```

I have even tried called set like this:

```
person.set({name: 'blank'}, {validate: true});
```

but that doesn't work either, I'm using version 1.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [the documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate):

> By default validate is called before save, but can also be called
>   before set if {validate:true} is passed.

Also, the event that is triggered is `invalid`, not `error`, so try this:

```
this.bind('invalid', function(model, error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```